# Refresh dropdown with Jquery

Tags: json, select

I have one dropdown for displaying the month from January to current month in jQuery mobile. I'm getting the data using JSON. But the problem is selected option is not getting refresh.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../modules/loadmonth.php?id=getoption&studid=" + $('#studentids').val(),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
            var sel;
            if (date[i].optval == date[i].curmon) {
                sel = "selected";
            } else {
                sel = "";
            }
            result = '<option value=' + data[i].optval + '' + sel + '>' + data[i].opt + '</option>';
        });
        $('#getmon').append(result);
    }
});
```

Comment: Add $('select[id="getmon"]').append(result).selectmenu('refresh', true); instead of $('#getmon').append(result);

Comment: I improved the formatting and reworded the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added **selectmenu** after append then it works.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../modules/loadmonth.php?id=getoption&studid=" + $('#studentids').val(),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
            var sel;
            if (date[i].optval == date[i].curmon) {
                sel = "selected";
            } else {
                sel = "";
            }
            result = '<option value=' + data[i].optval + '' + sel + '>' + data[i].opt + '</option>';
        });
        $('#getmon').append(result).selectmenu('refresh',true);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The `value` attribute should be in quotes, but more importantly you'll need a space between it and your `selected` attribute.

Comment: ya thank you.In drop box its showing nothing as selected.After click that dropdown is selected.I do no why its happening